# How to style jQuery sparklines outside of javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I've been trying the [jQuery sparklines plugin](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) and the style is applied in javascript
e.g.

```
$('#barchart').sparkline('html', { type:'bar', barColor:'green' });
```

Is there a solution to apply and change style in a circumstance like this without editing the scripts. For example in a css stylesheet or custom file with something like

```
.sparkline {
    type: bar;
    barColor: green;
}
```

Perhaps the javascript would look similar to this?

```
$('#barchart').sparkline('html', $.getStyle('sparkline'));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possbile, since this specific plugin is based on [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/canvas) and is completely drawn inside JavaScript. If it would use SVG, you could style the single SVG elements.

However, you can of course copy styles from other elements in the page:

```
var color = $('.brightgreen').css('background-color');
... barColor: color ...
```